# NetBeans não está conectando com o mysql

Tags: mysql, netbeans

estou tentando realizar a conexão entre o netbeans e o mysql, porém, quando sigo as instruções do **assistente de nova conexão** do netbeans aparece a seguinte mensagem: obs.: NetBeans IDE8.2

***Não é possível estabelecer uma conexão com jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull usando com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Could not create connection to database server.)***

Alguém sabe me dizer como faço para consertar este problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Anexa um print da sua tela de configuração.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O mySQL e chatinho de configurar pelo assistente de nova conexão por causa do timezone.

Tenta criar a URL de conexão na mão.
Usa o assistente de nova conexão até chagar na parte de inserir os dados. Põe lá o host, a porta e as demais informações. Bem na base do assistente vai aparecer uma url. Edita ela pra algo mais ou menos assim...

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<nomeDoBanco>?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
```

substitua o "`<nomeDoBanco>`" pelo nome da base que você está usando. Creio que assim vá funcionar.

[edit]

Olhando aqui no netbeans, ao que parece pode ser o conector que você está usando. Tenta baixar um conector mais atualizado. [Aqui](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.20) tem um link. Vai logo ali no começo da pagina, em ''files"  e baixa o .jar. Adiciona ela na pasta do projeto e logo no inicio do assistente("locate driver"), escolhe "MySQL", clica no botão add e linka o .jar que tá na pasta do projeto. Se o problema for o conector acho que assim irá funcionar.

Comment: Olá, fiz as alterações porém ainda está mostrando um erro...editei o post e coloquei o print da imagem

Comment: ok, pelo que está no print o nome do seu banco é "mysql"certo? então tenta usar essa url...`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC`. pode colar essa url direto no campo "JDBC URL".

Comment: Não é possível estabelecer uma conexão com jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC usando com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Could not create connection to database server.)

Comment: e se eu alterar o nome do banco consta esse erro:

Comment: Não é possível estabelecer uma conexão com jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/treino?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC usando com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Could not create connection to database server.)

Comment: Você está usando o conector certo(.jar)? tem o conector nas bibliotecas do projeto? qual a versão do mysql?

Comment: consegui dessa forma: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/treino?serverTimezone=UTC .. obrigada pela ajuda!!!